# How can I export a blender model as a sprite sheet?

Tags: rendering

I've got a bunch of models, and I now want to export each of them as a sprite sheet.

Specifically, I want to take multiple viewpoint renders of the models and save them out to a sprite sheet.

The only way I've managed to find to do this is to create an animation where I rotate the camera around the model, render the animation and then manually combine select frames from the animation.

Problematic because:

- Sometimes the animation tweening misses certain required frames (eg. cardinal directions), meaning I have to keyframe every frame.
- Can't seem to skip frames, so rendering animation takes ages, despite only need 32 frames of the entire thing.
- Tweening cameras from control-alt-0 to jump camera to view results occasionally in camera path getting confused, which messes up a few frames as the camera spins (often the frames I actually need).
- The model is lit, so multiple copies of the model rendered at once / rotating the model instead of the camera not an option.

It's rather problematic. I've been looking at trying to use a python script to automate this process, but I can't seem to get the render-to-file working as an operation.

Anyone know a better way of doing this?

Comment: What about using [this script](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Spritify)?

Comment: That's a neat script, but unfortunately it only seems to kick in once a render is complete. I'm really looking for a way to automate the tedious process of rendering 32 different views of a single scene.

Comment: You should be able to render a still frame from a python script with [`bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.render.html?#bpy.ops.render.render). You could write a script to automatically place/animate the camera and render out the frames you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround without using a script:

1. Add an empty to the center of you scene (or the center of your object, where ever you want the camera to rotate around):

   [image]
2. Parent the camera to the empty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

   [image]
3. With the empty selected, insert a rotation keyframe for the Z axis on frame 1 by hovering over the value and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> or right clicking and selecting *Insert Single Keyframe*:

   [image]
4. On frame `33` (one frame past frame `32`), insert another rotation keyframe for the Z axis setting the Z rotation to `360`, then set the scene *End* frame to `32`:

   [image]
5. Switch to the *graph editor*:

   [image]
6. In the graph editor, press <kbd>T</kbd> and select *linear* to remove the smooth interpolation of the keyframe:

   [image]
7. Render

The empty will be rotated to exactly `90°` on frame `9`, `180°` on frame `17`, and `270°` on frame `25`:

[image]

Here is an [example blendfile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25919).

Comment: oo, Thanks! That did the trick. The linear keyframe interpolation was the key thing that I was missing~