# Move along Line Path Not constantly

Tags: animation

How would I move an object along a line path in a non constant speed?

Like make the character take a step, then stay in the same spot for a few frames, then take another step and then repeat

I could animate the influence value but is there a way that I can simply loop the stop and go keyframes while he continues to follow the path?

Thanks

Comment: if your walk is not constant, why are you using a Follow Path constraint? Maybe it would be simpler to just animate your armature without any path

Comment: I have a walk cycle being repeated and I want to make it walk forward following a path. Except the way the character walks is not constant. What other method would be better?

Answer (score 2):

- See the NLA editor capabilities for this.  Repeat Loop. Let N1 and N2 be positive integers. So action can be repeated N1 times.  Then a period of no movement.  Then again an action can be repeated N2 times.
- Consider this as a quick note on NLA possibilities [How to generate a full sprite sheet automatically](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/how-to-generate-a-full-sprite-sheet-automatically/49959?r=SearchResults&s=1|31.0802#49959)
- Tutorials on NLA can be searched here at BSE or yoootooob or similar site on your selected search engine. This is not a tutorial on NLA.
- Insert keyframes for position on your Follow Path Constraint position. If the object moving happens to be an organic character then use keyframes on the motion of legs of character.

Comment: I don’t understand how this answers my question